# condition precedence in a loop and finishing a loop with one of two possible conditions

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, conditional-statements

this question has two questions:

1. is there a specific set of condition precedence rules relating to conditions in while loops?
2. how can i get one of two satisfied conditions (ie condition_x OR condition_y) to finish a loop?

**details:**

as a python newbie I am coming across a situation in a while loop where certain conditions are taking precedence over others.

I am trying to make:

1. one of two values required ie 'y' or 'n'
2. however if 'n' is chosen return a custom prompt which then allows the value 'ok'
3. and make it so that either the input of 'y' at step 1 OR 'ok' at step 3 would finish the loop

What is happening is that when entering 'n' the first condition is taking precedence and returning the statement:

```
please enter 'y' or 'n'
```

when I want it to be returning:

```
oh come on, enter 'ok'
```

**code:**

(I am aware the use of two `break`'s is probably wrong - I couldn't figure out how to get either 'y' OR 'ok' to finish the loop)

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input('question? (y/n)')
    my_string = 'here is a string '
    if len(user_input) == 0:
        print 'question? (y/n)'
    elif user_input is not 'y' or 'n':
        print 'please enter \'y\' or \'n\''
    elif user_input is 'n':
        print 'oh come on, enter \'ok\''
    elif user_input is 'ok':
        print my_string + ', ' \
        .join(list_var[:-1]), list_var[-1] + '?'
        break
    else:
        print my_string + ', ' \
        .join(list_var[:-1]), list_var[-1] + '?'
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing your boolean logic wrong; use:

```
elif user_input not in ('y', 'n'):
```

instead.

The expression `user_input is not 'y' or 'n'` is interpreted as `(user_input is not 'y') or ('n')`, which will *always* be True (non-empty strings are considered `True` in a boolean context):

```
>>> if 'n': print 'n!'
...
n!
```

You also should use `==` equality tests instead of `is` identity tests. `is` tests if the two operands are *the same object*, while `==` tests if the have the same value. For small strings that sometimes happens to be both True, but that is a Python optimization, not something you can rely on to work for all strings.

Next problem is that what happens when the user input is your over-use of `elif`. When `user_input` is `ok`, for example, it is *not* `y` or `n`, so `elif user_input not in ('y', 'n')` matches, *excluding all the other `elif` branches*.

You really want to simplify your logic:

```
if user_input not in ('y', 'n', 'ok'):
    print "please enter 'y' or 'n'"
elif user_input == 'n':
    print "oh come on, enter 'ok'"
else:
    print '{}{}{}?'.format(my_string, ', '.join(list_var[:-1]), list_var[-1])
    break
```

None of this has anything to do with `while` loops.

Comment: thank you for information on boolean logic, i have attempted to make the changes suggested and the code is running as desired when entering either 'y' (which finishes the loop) or any letter other than 'y' or 'n' (which returns the prompt to enter either 'y' or 'n') but when entering 'n' and then 'ok' it is not finishing the loop but rather returning back to the 'y' or 'n' prompt.  this link has code and interpreter panel:  http://labs.codecademy.com/nlL#:workspace

Comment: @user1063287: I cut down your branching to the minimum; you were overcomplicating things.

Comment: the prompt that is thrown back in the slimmed down implementation does not throw back the custom prompt but rather the 'y/n' prompt (http://labs.codecademy.com/nlz#:workspace).  the original does return the custom prompt (http://labs.codecademy.com/nlL#:workspace) however then returns the original prompt.  steps to replicate in both cases is to input 'n' and then 'ok'.  desired behaviour is inputting 'y' -> finishes loop, whereas inputting 'n' > custom prompt -> finishes loop.

Comment: @user1063287: You *print* an error, then it loops again to the same prompt. Your original code should have done the same, but it was broken otherwise. If you want the `input()` prompt to be different the next time, use a `msg` variable that you alter. The behaviour I gave you is consistent with your own code, albeit fixed to actually *work*.

Comment: @user1063287: Altered version that changes the `input()` prompt message instead: http://labs.codecademy.com/nlz/1#:workspace

Comment: pressing 'run' throws:  "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level".

Comment: hello, just for reference, here is a working version that is a little bit different but i was able to get it working with all required caveats: http://labs.codecademy.com/nlL/2#:workspace . thank you.